# Checking Licenses(SKUs) with AzureAZ

Tags: azure, powershell

Checking to see if anyone has been working with AzureAZ and gotten output for checking a users assigned license/sku. This would be similar to how Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail or Set-AzureADUserLicense works with AzureAD.

Sadly these cmdlets are only available on AzureAd(Windows Only) and not AzureAZ(PS Core)

Main Goal:
(Done)
I need to get a list of all accounts that are not enabled:

```
Get-AzAdUser | Select-Object DisplayName,AccountEnabled | Where-Object -Property AccountEnabled -NotLike "True"
```

(Pending)
Then get that list on a conditional to remove wasted licenses(E3,Power,others).

Would love to keep these scripts crossplatform, if there is no solution I'll be forced to re-write for AzureAD instead.

If anyone has a solution using AzureAZ I'll very much appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via AzureAZ. You should use Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail or Set-AzureADUserLicense or Office365 cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [AzureADPreview](https://www.poshtestgallery.com/packages/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.1.599.7) module which is in private preview. This module is supported in the **Powershell Core**.

**To install the module :**

```
 Register-PSRepository -Name PSTestGallery -SourceLocation https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2
 Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -Repository PSTestGallery
```

**To consume the module :**

```
Import-Module AzureADPreview
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId <String> -AssignedLicenses <AssignedLicenses>
```

**Note :**

When I checked at my end.

`Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail`  was not present.

However you can still update the license using the Set-AzureADuserLicense

**Other Alternative :**

Using Graph API from PowerShell.  (You could refer to the article [here](https://thesleepyadmins.com/2020/10/24/connecting-to-microsoft-graphapi-using-powershell/), which details on doing the same. )

You can make use of `Invoke-webrequest`/`invoke-Restmethod` to hit the Graph endpoints associated with Licensing.

- [Listing the License Details.](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [Assigning a License](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-assignlicense?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this on our Linux PowerShell Core Environment which is hosting GitLab. I did not check the Preview, pretty sure it's not yet ready for production but, it's nice to know that this is on the works.